# Best way for encapsulating the oracle and mysql

Tags: java, database

I have many kinds of db, some are oracle and some are  MySQL ,
so when i have an operation about transaction , how can i know which db should be operated. 
Have the ways to encapsulate for them to ensure the correct operation ?
what should i do to route these transaction to the correct db ? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Transactions are bound to connection and connection is bound to DB, i am not sure what do you want to achieve? how can i know which db should be operated, what do you mean?

Comment: yes ,you're right. But the kinds of DB are many(orace ,mysql,Sybase etc.) , and every DB has many dbs , if you want to operate some db ,you have to write one connection ,this is too big! so i want to know how can design this solution ? Maybe i have a bad expression!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database portability is a great goal to aim for, and is fully achievable for standard & even moderately complex business applications.

Practically, there are two main issues:

1)   Some databases (Oracle) have non-standard DDL, especially data-types. This can be converted easily, with search-and-replace.

2)   ID/ primary key generation has to be portable;  this rules out sequences & auto-generated columns. Use an allocator table instead, which can be completely portable as well as significantly more performant.

Using a persistence layer (such as Hibernate) helps insulate over a few other differences. I've had very good success making even major & complex applications, coming from a major migration and re-engineering project, portable from Oracle to MySQL.